# "Load more" for UL list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I have an unordered list:

```
<ul id="cont-new">
    <li>text 1</li>
    <li>text 2</li>
    <li>text 3</li>
    <li>text 4</li>
    <li>text 5</li>
    <li>text 6</li>
    <li>text 7</li>
    <li>text 8</li>
    <li>text 9</li>
    <li>text 10</li>
    <li>text 11</li>
    <li>text 12</li>
    <li>text 13</li>
    <li>text 14</li>
    <li>text 15</li>
</ul>

<a href="#" class="load-more">Load more</a>
```

Javascript

```
size_li = $("#cont-new li").size();

x_first = 8; 

$('#cont-new li:lt('+x_first+')').show();


 $(".load-more").click(function(e) 
 {
         x_first = (x_first+8 <= size_li) ? x_first+8 : size_li;

         $('#cont-new li:lt('+x_first+')').show();

       return false;
 });
```

I want to:

1. On page load - show first 8 items;
2. On page scroll - show next 8 items by 4 and show "Load more" link;
3. On "Load more" click - show 4 items at once, next 4 items show on page scroll and show "Load more";
4. Repeat step №3
5. If all items loaded, hide "Load more" link.

How can I best achieve this?

I have created the following jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rhsa0qyv/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.scroll` event handler you can attach your code inside of the event and register when the user reaches the bottom and attach another even that hides the button.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        x_first = (x_first+8 <= size_li) ? x_first+8 : size_li;
            $('#cont-new li:lt('+x_first+')').show();
    }
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       $(".load-more").hide();
   }
});
```

Made changes here:

https://jsfiddle.net/bjv6jvwo/1/

Documentation:

https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Answer (score 0):

May be this one will help
First add id element to your anchar tag
ex-`<a href="#" id="LoadMore" class="load-more">Load more</a>`
after doing it now update your jquery by using this code

```
size_li = $("#cont-new li").size();

x_first = 8; 

$('#cont-new li:lt('+x_first+')').show();


 $(".load-more").click(function(e) 
 {
         x_first = (x_first+8 <= size_li) ? x_first+8 : size_li;

         $('#cont-new li:lt('+x_first+')').show();
     if(x_first==size_li){$('#LoadMore').hide();}
       return false;
 });
```

Now you will get result.

Comment: was this helpful?